# How can i fix following error while building app

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details what is that error

I already tried gradle version and kotline to fix this issue

Comment: Can you share the code that's returning this error, and/or give us more specifics about what you're trying to accomplish?  [Have a look at the Stack documentation on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe we can help you once you provide a few more details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.